# How can I update a parent div height once the external div is load via animate()

Tags: jquery

I would appreciate all your input on this. I am loading an external div into a div called "pageLoader" from another html page.
 Once the div is loaded, I would like to animate the "pageLoader" height according to the external div's height. So if the
 external div's height is 800px then I would like "pageLoader" height to be the same. I have found couple of threads on this,
 but as I understand that I cannot get the externals divs height until it is loaded and only then I can get its dimensions.

This is my code. I would like height not to be hard coded. I would like a function to figure out the height of the external
 div and then update the height within ".animate block". I have tried numerous combination but have not been able to get it going.

```
        $("#pageLoader").load("xxxx.html #content").css(
        {                           
             display:"block",
             opacity:0,

        }).animate({

            opacity:1.0,
            top:0,
            easing: 'easOutBack',
            height: 

        },500, function()
        {
            //alert("DONE");
        });
```

Here is the code that would give me the height of the external div by calling a "callback" function:

```
        $('#pageLoader').load('xxxx.html', function() {
           $('#pageLoader').height($('#content').height());
        });
```

Any direction would highly be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly show the div, get its height, and hide it again. Then animate to the proper height.

Comment: So far so good. but if I hard code the height then it is tight coupling which is not a solution. thx